# print number is even

Tags: python

i am trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter a number & determines if the number is even or odd.

```
remainder = number%2

number = int(input ("number: ")

    if remainder == 0

    print("Number is even")

    else:

    print("Number is odd")
```

I keep getting a syntax error.

Comment: There are syntax errors all over the place. Missing parentheses, no indentation, missing colon - what error are you getting?

Comment: The error message should point to the line where the error occurs. That's the first place where you should look.

Comment: The python interpreter does a wonderful job of telling you *where* it found a syntax error. Start with that.

Comment: Doesn't look like you are reading the error message (nor your Python book)...

Comment: Give up programming and study something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   def evenOrOdd(number):
    if number%2 == 0:
        print "Even Number"
    else:
        print "Odd Number"
```

Answer (score 3):

Python requires indentation, as well as a : after the if statement. Here is a corrected version of the above that would work:

```
number = 7
remainder = number%2
if remainder == 0:
    print("Number is even")
else:
    print("Number is odd")

>>> Number is odd
```

That said, Jane Doe's slightly modified syntax is cleaner, and probably preferred for your application.

Comment: Also, remainder should be calculated after number is input.

Comment: IDLE would show you the syntax error with a big red bar on the missing ':'.  It won't debug logic errors, such as calculating the remainder before entering the number.